# Rails controller actions & cache - handling simultaneous/overlapping requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My Rails app depends on the Rails cache to temporarily hold user input and pass it between controller actions during the user log in process.  However, I realized that I have made a pretty serious error (since I am super-new to Rails and MVC, in general) and could use some help/advice/wisdom - basically, if two users are simultaneously (or nearly simultaneously) submitting data and going through the controller steps below, there's going to be some trouble - lost data, one user's data being entered as another, etc.  When I was building this, I did not understand the nature of controllers, though I for sure have a better idea now....

In short, here's how the code below is intended to work: a non-logged-in user fills out a form and submits that data which is passed to the `submission` action and held in a Rails cache object called `incoming_report`; the user is then prompted to log in (via Devise), and a successful log in triggers the `approval` controller action which reads the `incoming_report` cache object, saves that data to the database, and then creates a new cache object called `ids` to hang on to the id #'s of the user's entries; this redirects to the `summary` action which gathers up those ids and shows the corresponding data to the user as a summary of their entry.

`report_controller.rb`

```
#ON SUBMITTING THE FORM...
def submission
    @incomingReport = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:report])

    #SUBMITTED DATA IS HELD IN THE CACHE AS 'incoming_report' TO PASS TO approval CONTROLLER ACTION ON SUCCESSFUL LOGIN
    Rails.cache.write("incoming_report",@incomingReport)
end

#ON SUCCESSFUL LOG IN...
def approval
    @incomingReport = Rails.cache.read("incoming_report")
    @newReportIDArray = Array.new

    @incomingReport.each do |x|
        #DATA PROCESSING STUFF HERE...
    end

    #DELETE 'incoming_report' FROM CACHE
    Rails.cache.delete("incoming_report")

    #ID NUMBERS OF ENTRIES ARE HELD TO PASS TO summary CONTROLLER ACTION
    Rails.cache.write("ids",@newReportIDArray)

    redirect_to report_summary_path
end

#AFTER DATA IS ENTERED...
def summary
    @newReportIDs = Rails.cache.read("ids")
    #DELETE 'ids' FROM CACHE
    Rails.cache.delete("ids")
end
```

For the most part, this works very well, but if users cross each other during any of these actions, it's disastrous.  For instance, if one user hits the `submission` action while another user is busy logging in, the `incoming_report` object of the second user will overwrite that of the first user... and so on and so forth.

The main source of this problem is the fact that users log in after they have clicked the form submit button - the app must be structured that way - and the data can't be held in local/session storage objects because it includes base64 strings and is too long to employ those methods in certain browsers.  Holding this data on the server seemed like the best course of action until I noticed this issue...

Is there any way that I can prevent users from getting in each other's way in the controllers?  Or have I made a pretty fatal error?

**Editing to show solution**

Ultimately, using session variables instead of the Rails cache saved the day. Here's the reconfigured controller to show the solution...

```
def submission
    @incomingReport = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:report])

    @newReportIDArray = Array.new

    @incomingReport.each do |x|
        #DATA PROCESSING STUFF HERE
        @newReportIDArray.push(@new_report.id)
    end

    session[:ids] = @newReportIDArray

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json do
        render json: {
          success: 200
        }.to_json
      end
    end
end

def approval
    @reportIDs = session[:ids]

    @reportIDs.each do |x|
        @new_report = Report.find(x)
        @new_report.user_id = current_user.id
        @new_report.save
    end

    redirect_to report_summary_path
end


def summary
    @reportIDs = session[:ids]
end
```

Many thanks to the two folks who helped me on this and showed me the ways of the session variable.

I ran into a problem with the session variable being 'lost' between controller actions - [Rails / Devise - updating session variables between controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501992/rails-devise-updating-session-variables-between-controller-actions)

Comment: You should probably use the session, which is browser specific, instead of the cache.

Comment: @JohnNaegle Thank you!  You and Wade73 have given me good things to think about.

Comment: @JohnNaegle Awesome, thank you for your suggestion.  I had to rework the logic a bit, but using session variables totally fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you store the initial information into the database.  From there I would either save the id in a cookie or session variable.  You would then be able to retrieve the information from the database in the approval controller.  Another option I would consider would be to generate a guid as an id and pass that along to the sign in page as a query string parameter.  Store the guid in a hidden input tag, under the form tag.  Then when the user submits their credentials, you can also pass the guid.  At that point you log them in.  If successful, pull the guid from the posted data and then retrieve the database information with the guid.

Wade

Comment: that's funny, as I was walking down the street after posting this, I thought to myself 'why don't you just record the data on submission and then retain or delete it on successful/unsuccessful log in?'.  I have to think about this a bit, but I believe that you've set me on the right track - if I can get it to work, will for sure accept your answer.

Comment: Yes! I had to reconfigure the controllers and the logic a bit, but simply saving as a session variable worked. Thank you so much for your help! Editing my question to show solution...

Comment: No problem, enjoy your day!

Comment: actually, I misunderstood the problem, figured out a better way to ask - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39501992/rails-devise-updating-session-variables-between-controller-actions

Comment: To be honest I am new to Ruby on Rails, though I have been a web developer for a few years on ASP.Net.  Not sure I am going to be much help beyond what I provided.

Comment: @Wade23 - thanks man, it turned out to be a fairly messy problem having to do with the Devise gem and its various limitations.  I ended up solving my problem using AJAX to get data around the hurdles.

Comment: Good to hear, sorry I wasn't more helpful.